# Prove that three points are collinear

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a homework problem, I am tasked with proving the the three points (x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>), (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>), (x<sub>3</sub>, y<sub>3</sub>) are collinear iff

\begin{matrix}
        x1 & y1 & 1 \\
        x2 & y2 & 1 \\
        x3 & y3 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix} is equal to 0.

I honestly have no clue how to even start this proof.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How can you figure out if $3$ points are collinear *without* taking that determinant?  Or maybe even a more fundamental question you should ask yourself: what does the word "collinear" mean?

Comment: Is it EigenValues?

Comment: Forget about the matrix for a second.  You just have three points.  How do you determine whether all three are on the same line?

Comment: Adding (perhaps too much) to Bye_World’s hint: Points $A$, $B$, and $C$ are collinear if $AB$ and $AC$ have the same slope. Write down what it means for these two slopes to be the same in terms of your points’ coordinates. Also write out what it means for your determinant to be zero (by expanding the determinant. Do the two things you wrote down look like they might actually say the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collinear means the three points are on the same line $ax+by+c=0$, that is
$$\begin{pmatrix} x1 & y1 & 1 \\ x2 & y2 & 1 \\ x3 & y3 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}=0$$ The system only has a non-trivial solution for the coefficients $a,b,c$ iff the determinant is $0$.